# check page scroll in Chrome naturally (without Selenium) - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser

Does anyone know of a way to check if the scrollbar in Chrome has reached the bottom without using a detectable module like Selenium? Basically I just want the script to check a page that has already been opened in Chrome in a natural undetectable way to see if the scroll has reached bottom and if it hasn't then execute some code.

Comment: Is it about web scrape?

Comment: No web scraping. Just want to simply check scroll position in opened browser.